# Setting raw data of array with elements of dynamic size (vector to/from void*)

Tags: c++, vector

I need to store and restore a vector with elements of different size and want to adjust my solution to get this working. The goal is to get a size of the data in bytes + get a void pointer to the beginning of the data.

I use a template class in my code and combine solution 1 and 2 in it, but for the sake of simplicity I split the code up in this question.

**1) Solution for a vector of elements where all elements have the same size:**

*1.1) Save a vector as raw data - with fixed size elements, e.g. int:*

```
std::vector<int> data;
Sint32 size = sizeof(int) * vec.size();
void* tdata = static_cast<void*>(&vec[0]);
// tdata points to the raw data => I can work with this now and save it to my memory structure (tdata + size is saved there)
```

*1.2) Restore a vector from raw data - with fixed size elements, e.g. int:*

```
std::vector<int> vec;
size_t size = ...; // received from my memory structure
void* tdata = ...; // received from my memory structure

int count = size / sizeof(int);
vec.resize(count);
memcpy(&vec[0], tdata, size);
// vec contains count elements of type int now
```

**2) Solution for a vector of elements where all elements have dynamic sizes:**

I simply define two helper interfaces/classes to get the size of all elements inside the vector:

```
class ObjectWithSize
{
    public:
        // eg. for an int + char*: sizeof(int) + strlen(text) + 1
        virtual int getRawSize() = 0; 
};

class RawDataWithCount
{
    public:
        int count;
        void* data;
};
```

*2.1) Save a vector of dynamic elements:*

```
Sint32 datasize = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) 
    datasize += vec.at(i).getRawSize();
RawDataWithCount data = RawDataWithCount();
data.count = vec.size();
data.data = static_cast<void*>(&vec[0]);
void* tdata = static_cast<void*>(&data);
// tdata points to the raw data => I can work with this now and save it to my memory structure (tdata + datasize is saved there)
```

*2.2) Restore a vector of dynamic elements*

```
std::vector<T> vec;
size_t size = ...; // received from my memory structure
void* tdata = ...; // received from my memory structure
RawDataWithCount* data = reinterpret_cast<RawDataWithCount*>(tdata);
int count = data->count;
vec.resize(count);
memcpy(&vec[0], data->data, size);
```

**Information**

Solution 1 is used for a long time already and works quite good, solution 2 will be an extension of it for the future. I think, 2.1 is save to use, but when it comes to 2.2 I'm not sure anymore, so here comes the question. Tests show that solution 2 seems to work, but I want to know if it is save.

**Question**

Is it save to do following in 2.2

```
vec.resize(count);
memcpy(&vec[0], data->data, size);
```

if the elements of `vec` do not all have the same size? I assume not, but I'm unsure here. If this is not save, maybe someone has a better suggestion? (I know I can manually solve this by simple creating a raw data in 2.1 with number of elements followed by a list of size/element, then parsing back elements 1 by 1 in 2.2 and fill up the vector with this data, but maybe (like in case 1)
 there is a more simple solution with the help of a vector?)

Comment: This catched my eye: _if the elements of `vec` do not all have the same size_ IMHO, all elements of a `std::vector<T>` have the same size by definition - the size of `T`.

Comment: +1 for detailed explanation but -1 for not providing a [mcve]. Details matter, so it would be good if you could post a complete example

Comment: From [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector): _The elements are stored contiguously, which means that elements can be accessed not only through iterators, but also using offsets to regular pointers to elements. This means that a pointer to an element of a vector may be passed to any function that expects a pointer to an element of an array._

Comment: `Sint32` – *if* you can (acknowledging that there might be reasons not to do so), prefer the C++ standard types from `<cstdint>` header over custom defined types, i. e. `int32_t` in given case.

Comment: @Scheff I'm resizing and memcopying into the vector (the vector can't know how much memory is copied into it in case 2 even if it knows how many elements it will hold), I'm not filling it via push_back or similar - that's why my question arises... so your quote shows me, that 2.1 is valid, but not if 2.2 will work reliably as far as I can see... and the size of T is not fixed in case 2

Comment: About your last question: In *general*, it is *not* safe to use memcpy (you might e. g. end up in two distinct objects holding pointers to the same data and thus in double deletion, many other faulty scenarios could occur as well), in some *specific* scenarios, it *can* be safe, though.

Comment: _and the size of T is not fixed in case 2_ ...but still all elements of `std::vector<T>` will have the same size. The size of a type `T` is determined at compile time and may not change at runtime. At runtime it is _fixed_.

Comment: _the vector can't know how much memory is copied_ The vector provides storage per requirement in `std::vector::resize()`. If you override its internal data via `memcpy()` it still has the same size afterwards. Whether the data in `std::vector<>` is still intact/valid/reliabe after `memcpy()` is beyond the responsibility of `std::vector<>` but it will assume that's intact and deal with that under that assumption (e.g. on further `resize()`s or accesses or destruction).

Comment: I don't understand what's your intention. If T is a struct that holds a char* and I have 2 elements, one with the char* holding "test\0" and one with "test long\0", then the 2 elements have different sizes (5 vs 10 bytes) and so mem copying 15 bytes into a vector that is resized to 2 can't know where the first element ends and where the second starts... That's where my question comes in and I don't know what you want to tell me. It looks like you want to tell me it will work, but based on my example it's not understandable how the vector can know where element 1 ends and where el. 2 starts...

Comment: That's wrong. You would store them in a `std::vector<char*>` and every element is a `char*` and has the size of `char*`. Or, you would store them in a `std::vector<char>` and every element has the size of `char`. - Whatever you `memcpy()` into a `std::vector<T>` (`char*`s or `char[]`s or whatever), the `std::vector<T>` will handle elements of `T`. And, it doesn't care what you cheat into its data by re-interprete casts. But, as already mentioned, this is a good way to shoot in your own foot.

Comment: _If T is a struct that holds a char*_ than `sizeof(T)` is `sizeof(char*)` or `sizeof(char*)` + X if it has virtual methods and/or include fill bytes due to packing/alignment. But still a `std::vector<T>` will have all elements of same `sizeof(T)`.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I got your point know. Would you have an alternative suggestion for my problem instead of memcpy?

Comment: Dumping arbitrary data in/out accessing raw bytes of data is something which I consider as dangerous in general. It works at best for primitive types on the same platform. For portable solution, endianess, alignment, etc. may become an issue even for primitive types. In general, I would recommend [C++ FAQ: Serialization and Unserialization](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization) for an overview.